# Unable to play video through MSE (Media Source Extensions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

Trying to use MSE (Media Source Extensions) to play video. I am able to get chunks in Ajax response and appending to sourceBuffer as well but while playing its not playing. Here is the sample code which i have written...

```
        function playMedia(src) {
          var BasicPlayer = function () {
                var self = this;
                this.initiate = function (sourceFile) {

                    if (!window.MediaSource || !MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"')) {
                          self.setState("Your browser is not supported");
                          return;
                    }
                    self.clearUp();
                    self.sourceFile = sourceFile;
                    self.videoElement = VIDEO;
                    self.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
                    self.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function () {
                          self.createSourceBuffer();
                    }, false);
                    //append the video element to the DOM
                    self.videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(self.mediaSource);
                    self.videoElement.pause();
                    $('#basic-player').append($(self.videoElement));
              }
              this.clearUp = function() {
                    if (self.videoElement) {
                        //clear down any resources from the previous video embed if it exists
                        $(self.videoElement).remove();
                        delete self.mediaSource;
                        delete self.sourceBuffer;
                    }
              }
                this.setState = function (state) {
                      alert(state);
                }
                this.createSourceBuffer = function () {
                    self.sourceBuffer = self.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4');
                    self.sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function () {
                        self.setState("Ready");
                        self.videoElement.play();
                    }, false);
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', self.sourceFile, true);
                    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                    xhr.onload = function (e) {
                        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                            self.setState("Failed to download video data");
                            self.clearUp();
                        } else {
                            alert("chunk received...");
                            if(xhr!=null && xhr.response!=null){
                                var arr = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
                                if (!self.sourceBuffer.updating) {
                                    self.setState("Appending video data to buffer");
                                    self.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arr);
                                    alert(self.sourceBuffer);
                                } else {
                                    self.setState("Source Buffer failed to update");
                                }
                            }else{
                                self.setState(xhr.response+"");
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.onerror = function () {
                        self.setState("Failed to download video data");
                        self.clearUp();
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                    self.setState("Downloading video data");
              }
          }
        var basicPlayer = new BasicPlayer();

        window.updatePlayer = function (sourceFile) {
            basicPlayer.initiate(sourceFile);
        }
        updatePlayer(src);
    }
```

Comment: At a glance code looks OK. Any exceptions on the console? It would also be helpful if you  provide us with the content of chrome://media-internals and your test file.

Comment: I just noticed that you have not specified any codec when calling `addSourceBuffer`. Try `addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42e01e, mp4a.40.2"');`

Comment: How are you chunking your content? MSE expects a certain structure to the buffers you append to the source buffer... See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/30643655/83169

Comment: addSourceBuffer('video/mp4') is working fine. code is downloading content in single chunk but while i am calling play it shows HAVE_METADATA in player statistics and seeking status but not playing video.