# Prepare mp4 videos for Media Source Extensions API using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This command produce init.mp4 + bunch of m4s files, i'm trying to play them using MSE :

```
ffmpeg -i <input file> -f hls -hls_segment_type fmp4 -c:v copy playlist.m3u8
```

This is the client side code i'm using:

```
var socket = io();
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2"'; 
if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
} else {
    console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}
function sourceOpen (_) {
  var mediaSource = this;
  var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
  sourceBuffer.mode = 'sequence'; 
  socket.on('broadcast', function (newPiece) {
      // here i'm getting the buffer of the video  == buffer
      sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
        video.play().then(function() { }).catch(function(error) { });
      });
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer); // when the seconde video comes i append it's buffer
  })
};
```

Everything works fine when i send `init.mp4` file followed by `playlist0.m4s, playlist1.m4s, playlist2.m4s, ....`. 
But when i try to play  `init.mp4` file followed immediately 6,7,8 not 0,1,2 meaning `playlist6.m4s, playlist7.m4s, playlist8.m4s, ....`, it didn't work. 
I don't know why, this supposed to be live video, the viewer that is watching the live from the beginning gets `init.mp4, playlist0.m4s, playlist1.m4s, playlist2.m4s, ....`. 
Someone that came after 5 minutes gets something like this  `init.mp4, playlist32.m4s, playlist33.m4s, playlist34.m4s, ....` and so on, but so far it works only for the viewer that get's `init.mp4, playlist0.m4s, playlist1.m4s, playlist2.m4s, ....`. the video can't play for the others

Comment: Is WebM required? If not you might try mp4/h.264.

Comment: @heff WebM is not required, no problem if it's mp4 as long as it works well with Media Source Extensions API, if you have a working example i'll be appreciated if you put it as an answer

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643655/83169. You have to work on the client side so you can chunk the `fMP4` in `moof+mdat` segments.

Comment: @PabloMontilla i saw your answer while i was searching but i didn't understand it, i'm a beginner to ffmpeg and mse, can you please post the code you mean as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `fMP4` instead of `webm`, you can generate a suitable fragmented `MP4` using the following command line (geared towards low latency):

```
ffmpeg -i <input file> -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v <bitrate> -preset medium -tune zerolatency -flags +cgop+low_delay -movflags empty_moov+omit_tfhd_offset+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+isml -c:a aac <output file.mp4>
```

Be sure to use the latest version.

You'll still need to parse the generated `MP4` output to send the web client an initialization segment with the `moov` box, and pairs of `moof+mdat` boxes as segments for MSE to play video.

Comment: thanks it needs lot of work, i found that i can use this command `ffmpeg -i <input file> -f hls -hls_segment_type fmp4 -c:v copy playlist.m3u8`, then send to the browser `init.mp4` followed by `playlist0.m4s, playlist1.m4s, playlist2.m4s, ...` this work fine , but the problem when i try it like this `init.mp4, playlist5.m4s, playlist6.m4s, ...` it didn't work, i don't know why. it suppose to be like live video, meaning someone can watch it from the beginning someone after 10 minutes, i mean you can't send `init.mp4, playlist0.m4s, playlist1.m4s, ...` to someone that came after 10 minutes

Comment: You basically have two standard options: HLS (the only one supported by iOS devices) and DASH. Both can use fMP4, and both use a file that describes the different video segments (an .m3u8 or .xml manifest). If what you want is to allow people to see a video adapting to their bandwidth, then you need to use HLS or DASH and a suitable player on the client (Shaka [https://github.com/google/shaka-player] for example). If you want to stream a live event, you probably can adapt the HLS or DASH way to your needs. Otherwise you have to code yourself something doing what I'm telling you in the answer.

Comment: what you suggested in your answer needs more code + the mp4 files are too big compared to `playlist.m4s`, if there  a way i can play the video like this `init.mp4, playlist8.m4s, playlist9.m4s, ...` i mean not in successive way would be good, i will update my question so you understand what i mean

Comment: You can simply change the `video.currentTime` to be the correct time. Your problem is that you are adding segments in the future, but the player tries to start at the beginning. You can see what is the time corresponding to the loaded segments by looking at `video.buffered`.

Comment: i'm a beginner this is my first time with MSE and video, can you please show me how can i change `video.currentTime` to the correct one by looking at `video.buffered` like you said

Comment: `video.currentTime = video.buffered.start(0);`

Comment: it didn't work it gives me `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'TimeRanges': The index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0).`. when i send `init.mp4,1,2,3` it gives me the error above and when ever it receive a chunk it start the video from the beginning , when i send `init.mp4, 6,7,8` it gives me the error above and + it didn't play the video at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164632/discussion-between-pablo-montilla-and-ler).