# How to get a live stream of a computer's desktop to web browser video with the lowest latency possible?

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

I am trying to make a remote desktop protocol that runs in your web browser.
This is what I have so far in order to capture the desktop (on windows):

```bash
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -c:v libx264rgb -preset ultrafast -f mp4 out.mp4
```

Which seems to work great to capture to a file.

I have tried just piping the data out from ffmpeg to a web server and playing it in a web browser, but the video just spins and fails to load.
I've also tried changing the video format but then I lose a lot of my FPS and the video still fails to load.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Media Source Extensions (MSE). You can either use `WebP` or `fMP4` with `h.264`. In case of using `h.264`, you have to use fragmented output and pipe the fragments as you get them in a named pipe for example.

Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643655/83169 which explains the `FFmpeg` parameters you need to generate correct fragmented output usable with MSE.

Comment: The video still just spinning. A full code example would be appreciated.